# can this customization in yii be done

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

i have displayed  images and its name but i need to display is when i mouse over any image its particular  the  brand and price must be displayed . here what happens is only the 1st image price and brand displayed for all image when i ouse over on any of the images not that particular images data. i do know ajax must be used but am a new be to ajax with yii.price and brand are display none.on mouseover its display block

view/controllerA/index

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function () {
//$.getJSON('$arr', function (data) {
    //alert(<?php echo $arr; ?>);
    $("#pcontent").html('');
    $.each(<?php echo $arr; ?>, function (i, em) {

        $("#pcontent").append('<div class="product"><div><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php/controllerA/displayview/id/' + em.pid +'"><img onmouseover="Big();" onmouseout="Small();" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/' + em.pimg + '" width="135" height="138"/></a><div class="title">' + em.name + '</div></div><div id="bigOne" class="meBig"><div class="title">Price:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + em.price + '</div><div class="title">Brand:&nbsp;&nbsp;'+ em.brand + '</div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');

    });


//});
$("#pcontent").fadeIn(2000);

   });
function Big() {

    document.getElementById('bigOne').style.display = "block";
 }

 function Small() {
document.getElementById('bigOne').style.display = "none";
 }
   </script>
```

controller/contollerA

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $db = controllerB::model()->fnprod();
    $arr = CJSON::encode($db);
    $this->render('index',array('arr'=>$arr));
}
```

i dont want the model to appear in the mebig div my need is only the that to fields with css must be displayed can anyone please guide am loosing my mind on this .

Comment: How are you displaying your images?

Comment: sorry for the delay ... ...   $("#pcontent").append('<div class="product"><div><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php/controllerA/displayview/id/' + em.pid +'"><img onmouseover="Big();" onmouseout="Small();" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/' + em.pimg + '" width="135" height="138"/></a><div class="title">' + em.name + '</div></div><div id="bigOne" class="meBig"><div class="title">Price:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + em.price + '</div><div class="title">Brand:&nbsp;&nbsp;'+ em.brand + '</div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');
 i am displaying\

Comment: add this code to your question by editing. So it will be more clear than now

Comment: it does contain there in the script tags ... $("#pcontent").append( ... as folows